# Generate multi-dimensional array from an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've a list of associative arrays as below:

```
[
"country" => "AU",
"state" => "VIC",
"suburb" => "Carlton",
"precedence" => ["country", "state", "suburb"]
]
```

And I want a new multidimensional array like below where the elements are nested based on the order defined by *precedence* key on first array:

```
[
 "country" => [
  "AU" => [
    "state" => [
      "VIC" => [
        "suburb" => "Carlton
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
]
```

The above is just an example and I want a generic solution that will work for any kinds of array. Only 1 condition that'll be satisfied by all input arrays is that they'll have a *precedence* element denoting the order in which the output array needs to be generated.

I've tried some recursive solution but it's not working as expected and I've got PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (looks like it's running infinitely):

```
function generateArray(&$array)
    {
        foreach ($array['precedence'] as $key => $property) {
            if ($key == sizeof($array['precedence']) - 1) {
                return [$property => $array[$property]];
            } else {
                return generateAssetConfig($array);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why do you need to make this structure? what if you need `state` as-is, if its this structure then you won't know if its a key or the final value after all the nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop the reversed items of the precedence part.

If there are no items in the result array yet, add the first key => value pair.

Else wrap the current result in a multidimensional array, setting the current value if the iteration as the outer key, and wrap the value (for that key in the source array) together with the current result in a second array.

```
$source = [
    "country" => "AU",
    "state" => "VIC",
    "suburb" => "Carlton",
    "precedence" => ["country", "state", "suburb"]
];

function generateArray($array)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach(array_reverse($array["precedence"]) as $v) {
        $result =! $result ? [$v => $array[$v]] : [$v => [$array[$v] => $result]];
    }
    return $result;
}

var_export(generateArray($source));
```

Output

```
array (
  'country' => 
  array (
    'AU' => 
    array (
      'state' => 
      array (
        'VIC' => 
        array (
          'suburb' => 'Carlton',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you everyone! All of the below answers are correct as well but I found this one to be simplest so I've upvoted it.

Comment: Wow, great solution! I couldn't even think about this. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function generateNestedArray($arr) {
  $precedence = $arr['precedence'];
  $nestedArray = [];
  for ($i = count($precedence)-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $key = $precedence[$i];
    if (!$nestedArray) {
      $nestedArray[$key] = $arr[$key];
    } else {
      $nestedArray = [$key => [ $arr[$key]=> $nestedArray]];
    }
  } 
  
  return $nestedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simplest solution (recursive function):**

```
function generateArrayRecursion($array, $precedenceIndex = 0) {
    $precedence = $array['precedence'];
    
    return [
        $precedence[$precedenceIndex] => $precedenceIndex === \count($precedence) - 1
            ? $array[$precedence[$precedenceIndex]]
            : [$array[$precedence[$precedenceIndex]] => generateArrayRecursion($array, $precedenceIndex + 1)]
    ];
}
```

**Alternative solution (loop and array references):**

```
function generateArray($array) {
    $precedence = $array['precedence'];
    $result = [];
    $lastKey = $precedence[count($precedence) - 1];

    $currentElement = &$result;
    foreach ($precedence as $key) {
        if ($key === $lastKey) {
            $currentElement[$key] = $array[$key];
        } else {
            $currentElement[$key] = [$array[$key] => []];
            $currentElement = &$currentElement[$key][$array[$key]];
        }
    }
    
    return $result;
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
$array = [
    "country" => "AU",
    "state" => "VIC",
    "suburb" => "Carlton",
    "precedence" => ["country", "state", "suburb"]
];

var_dump(generateArrayRecursion($array));
var_dump(generateArray($array));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive algorithm to do this:

```
<?php

$raw = [
    [
        "country" => "AU",
        "state" => "VIC",
        "suburb" => "Carlton",
        "precedence" => ["country", "state", "suburb"]
    ],
    [
        "country" => "AU",
        "state" => "NSW",
        "suburb" => "Sydney",
        "precedence" => ["country", "state", "suburb"]
    ]
];

function generateFromPrecedence($array)
{
    if (!isset($array['precedence']))
        throw new Exception('Precedence array does not exist');

    if (!empty(array_diff($array['precedence'], array_diff(array_keys($array), ['precedence']))))
        throw new Exception('Keys and precendence keys different');

    return generateStructure($array);
}

function generateStructure($array, $precedence = 0)
{
    if ($precedence == count($array['precedence'])-1)
        return [$array['precedence'][$precedence] => $array[$array['precedence'][$precedence]]];

    return [$array['precedence'][$precedence] => [$array[$array['precedence'][$precedence]] => generateStructure($array, ++$precedence)]];
}

$output = generateFromPrecedence($raw[0]);

var_dump($output);
```

Outputs:

```
array(1) {
["country"]=>
array(1) {
    ["AU"]=>
    array(1) {
    ["state"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["NSW"]=>
        array(1) {
        ["suburb"]=>
        string(6) "Sydney"
        }
    }
    }
}
}
```